# Android Live-Streaming using MediaCodec and TextureView

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application that plays a video by received the 'raw video frames' from the client to the server using TCP in 'real-time'.

For test, I made a client application that sends sequential bytes of selected video file to the server application, after receiving all bytes and converting them to the complete mp4 file in the server part, then I could play it successfully.

Then I have a new problem: how display video frames received from the client in 'real time'. ※In the above test project, each chunks of bytes are not pure video frames so I can't play them as video in real time.

I have searched that RTSP can help this, but I have no time (3 days left to complete this project..) to analyze RTSP libraries, so I decided to use primitive way to implement live-streaming application.

And I have tried using MediaCodec, MediaExtractor, MediaMuxer and TextureView, but I failed to play the result video, because maybe I miscomprehend using MediaCodec properly. Well I just decode a local video file and store entire video frames and meta-data(such as presentationTimeUs and flags of BufferInfo), and then in result activity, used muxer to combine them to new result video file, but I failed.

Anyway, I want to know the sure method to complete this project.
Also I can provide my decoder and muxer code if you need.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.